# Наложение эффектов на изображения, подобие Instagram

Tags: jquery, php, imagemagick, kohana, javascript

Здравствуйте! Требуется реализовать наложение эффектов на изображения - некое подобие Instagram(только на PHP или JavaScript).
В данный момент смотрю в сторону ImageMagick, но всё таки хочется что-нибудь по проще, может что-то на JavaScript и т.п.
Вот решил узнать мнения опытных пользователей, по этому поводу.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [урок на английском](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-instagram-filters-with-php/) по как раз обработке изображений а-ла Instagram, на PHP.

Comment: @sergiks, спасибо